# Scrambled arrays - checking if elements in the arrays match (order doesnt matter) with O(n) complexity

Tags: c

I'm trying to write code that takes two arrays, returns 1 if they're elements match (order doesnt matter) or 0 if they do not match.

1. must be O(n)

I've written a few different algorithms, one that compares sums of the two arrays returning 1 if they're the same, 0 if they're not but if the arrays contain different value elements that sum up to the same thing then this doesnt work.

Finding one that is O(n^2) is simple (two for loops, comparing, then iterating for the next position of A etc..

I cant seem to figure out a O(n) that does this. The current code I have takes the difference of the values and returns 1 if its 0. Still doesnt know how to deal with scrambled arrays that arent sorted the same. Is there a O(n) that does this?

```
int scrambled( unsigned int a[], unsigned int b[], unsigned int len)
{
    int count[100];
    int flag = 1;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        count[a[i]]++;
        count[b[i]]--;
    }

    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        if(count[i] != 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return flag;
```

Comment: The code you posted is an O(n) solution that uses a technique similar to a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). So I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: It takes the difference between a[i] and b[i] and iterates through i but it doesnt account for when for ex. 2 is at a[2] and at b[4]. Order isn't supposed to affect the return value - ex. [1,2,3]=a and [3,1,2]=b should return 1 because they have the same elements regardless of order

Comment: Perhaps you should try it with those example arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++11, `std::unordered_set` could be populated in `O(n)` time and then you could perform `O(n)` element membership tests (it's still `O(n)` even if you do it twice; constant multipliers don't count).

If C++11 is out, you could still use the same basic algorithm with a hand-written hash set, or if the elements of each are in a bounded range, you could use a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (which is `O(n+k)` thanks to being specialized for ranges of numbers, if the range is small, the `k` component doesn't matter much).

Comment: Ah, does this account for same element but unordered arrays?ie. [1,2,3]=a and [3,1,2]=b?

Comment: @Code_Penguin: Yes. In the case of a counting sort based approach, you're essentially constructing new arrays of size equal to the range of possible values, then comparing those, and they're created with "order". With hash sets, you're removing ordering from the equation, just making it possible to do insertions and later lookups efficiently; constructing a hash set in a different order might produce a different iteration order, but it doesn't matter for simple membership testing.

Comment: The elements are in a range from [0 99]. So I think the counting sort method will be best here. Thank you ShadowRanger!

Comment: So should I first put the two arrays together, then apply counting sort?

Comment: No. The most obvious if slightly less efficient approach would be to count each array independently, then `memcmp` the resulting arrays of counts (don't need to reproduce the original array of values form). The most efficient approach would be to count one array, then go over the second array decrementing the counts from the first array. If any decrement operation brings an index in the array of counts below 0, you're done; they weren't equal. If you finish decrementing without anything going negative (and you already compared lengths to start, because that's easy), then they are equal.