# Check 2 arrays if they have the same content, ignoring order, no sorting. What is the most efficient algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Examples of arrays for which scrambled should return 1:

```
a = {10,15,20}, b = {10,15,20}
a = {99}, b = {99}
a = {1,2,3,4,5}, b = {5,3,4,2,1}
a = {}, b = {} (i.e. len = 0)
a = {2,1,3,4,5}, b = {1,2,4,3,5}
```

Examples of arrays for which scrambled should return 0:

```
a = {1,1}, b = {1,2}
a = {10,15,20}, b = {10,15,21}
a = {1,2,3,4,5}, b = {5,3,4,2,2}
```

My code in C is like this, but it is a O(N^2) not very efficient.

```
int scrambled( unsigned int a[], unsigned int b[], unsigned int len )
{
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    for (int i=0; i< len; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<len; j++)
        {
            if (a[i]==b[j])
            {
                count1++;
                break;
            }       
        }

        for (int j=0; j<len; j++)
        {
            if (b[i]==a[j])
            {
                count2++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return (count1 == len && count2 == len );


}
```

Above code is flawed. Is there a linear solution for this?

Comment: Test your code against `{ 1, 2, 2, 3, 5 }` and `{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 }`, it will return true.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931556/scrambled-arrays-checking-if-elements-in-the-arrays-match-order-doesnt-matter

Comment: @DiWang: Does this solution also work if the arrays have duplicate elements?

Comment: My code above is flawed. But the algorithm from that link, Yes, it works. please see my updated code below.

Comment: @DiWang Answers should go into the "Answer" box (use the "Answer Your Question" button below). Please not put your answer in the Question box - this confuses people who might read your question in future....... BTW I see you were given advice to put your answer together with the question; this is bad advice. There is a dedicated box for answers; use it.

Comment: I was just asked to update my post instead putting in the Questions. now I am moving it back to the Answer box. I am confused.

Comment: @DiWang Explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Take the sum, the mean and the variance. If they are not identical, the arrays are different. If they are identical, either someone has very carefully cooked the books, or they are identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that can be implemented with O(n) complexity:

1. Create a hash map for each array. The key is the array element. The value is the number of occurences.
2. Iterate over the keys of the first hash 
   map and check if the value is the same for both hash maps.
3. If all values are the same, the arrays are equal.

Comment: Actually, it should not necessarily be a hash table. You can use any data structure that supports fast lookup and insertion. If you don't want to use a hash table, you can use an array (advantage: very easy) or some sort of a search tree (advantage: space complexity is low).

Comment: @anatolyg: Yes, in many practical cases these would work equally well or even better than a hash map. Still they are not as general. Arrays only work with integer elements (to be used as index) and you need to know the range. When using trees the time complexity of the algorithm will in general be O(n log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

This is the fixed code.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int scrambled( unsigned int a[], unsigned int b[], unsigned int len )
{
    int count [99] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        count [a[i]]++;
        count [b[i]]--;     
    }
    for (int i=0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        if (count[i]!=0){return 0;}
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This only works if the array elements are integers with a limited range, in this case [0,98]. And it is not really O(n) but O(max(n,m)) where m is the size of the range.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. we have to know all the possible elements first.